# Is it really a default practice to make every monad transformer an instance of MonadTrans?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, scotty

So *Real World Haskell* says:

> Every monad transformer is an instance of MonadTrans

but I'm playing with *Scotty* and found out that its base monad transformer `ScottyT` is *not* an instance of `MonadTrans`.

Looking at the release notes it seems that it is a deliberate design decision: [here](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/blob/master/changelog.md#0100). Quote:

> The monad parameters to ScottyT have been decoupled, causing the type of the ScottyT constructor to change. As a result, ScottyT is no longer a MonadTrans instance ...

I hope you understand my confusion. Nevertheless, I will try to formulate strict questions:

- Why would one not want a monad transformer to be an instance of `MonadTrans`?
- How would you explain the aforementioned change in ScottyT design?

P.S.: I do understand that I can define an instance of `MonadTrans ScottyT` myself, but should I? (links back to questions)

Comment: Perhaps the question is "Is `ScottyT` a monad transformer if it isn't an instance of `MonadTrans`?"

Comment: Thanks, Eric, I had it popping in my head, but if you look f.x. at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers it never states that MonadTrans is a prerequisite for somethingT to be a monad tranformer. It is more phrased as nice to have. check the line: 

`Technically, this is all we need; however, it is convenient to make MaybeT an instance of a few other classes`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ScottyT` is not a monad transformer. Let's inline the (simplified) definition:

```
newtype ScottyT' m a = ScottyT' {
   runS :: State [ (Request->m Response) -> Request->m Response ] a
  }
```

To define `lift` for this you would need, from a general `m a` action and such a middlewares list, have to obtain an actual `a` value, because `State s` yields actual unmonadic values. There's no way to do that.

Now, if you argue that `MonadTrans` isn't actually required for something to be a monad transformer: mathematically speaking, monad transformers correspond to a composition of functors, but `ScottyT` doesn't actually implement such a composition.

Comment: thank you for the answer! It's a lot clearer to me now. Do you mind fixing/rephrasing the second sentence? I think either a junction is missing or I'm too much of a newbie to parse it.